# python I got a complex multiple nested JSON file, how to convert to csv file

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

Here is my code, It can only convert part of the JSON file, it fails to flatten all JSON，Unable to convert all files

```
import pandas as pd
import json
all_data = []
add_header = True
with open('C:\\Users\\jeri\\Desktop\\1.json',encoding='utf-8') as f_json:
    for line in f_json:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            all_data.append(json.loads(line))
df = pd.json_normalize(all_data)
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\jeri\\Desktop\\11.csv', index=False,encoding='utf-8',header=add_header)
add_header = False
```

my json file

```
{"id":"aa","sex":"male","name":[{"Fn":"jeri","Ln":"teri"}],"age":45,"info":[{"address":{"State":"NY","City":"new york"},"start_date":"2001-09","title":{"name":"Doctor","Exp":"head"},"year":"2001","month":"05"}],"other":null,"Hobby":[{"smoking":null,"gamble":null}],"connect":[{"phone":"123456789","email":"info@gmail.com"}],"Education":"MBA","School":{"State":"NY","City":"new york"}}
{"id":"aa","sex":"female","name":[{"Fn":"lo","Ln":"li"}],"age":34,"info":[{"address":{"State":"NY","City":"new york"},"start_date":"2008-11","title":{"name":"Doctor","Exp":"hand"},"year":"2008","month":"02"}],"other":null,"Hobby":[{"smoking":null,"gamble":null}],"connect":[{"phone":"123456789","email":"info@gmail.com"}],"Education":"MBA","School":{"State":"NY","City":"new york"}}
```

The result of the conversion is below,Not all json files are converted，this is not what i want，I need to flatten and convert all files,

```
id,sex,name,age,info,other,Hobby,connect,Education,School.State,School.City
aa,male,"[{'Fn': 'jeri', 'Ln': 'teri'}]",45,"[{'address': {'State': 'NY', 'City': 'new york'}, 'start_date': '2001-09', 'title': {'name': 'Doctor', 'Exp': 'head'}, 'year': '2001', 'month': '05'}]",,"[{'smoking': None, 'gamble': None}]","[{'phone': '123456789', 'email': 'info@gmail.com'}]",MBA,NY,new york
aa,female,"[{'Fn': 'lo', 'Ln': 'li'}]",34,"[{'address': {'State': 'NY', 'City': 'new york'}, 'start_date': '2008-11', 'title': {'name': 'Doctor', 'Exp': 'hand'}, 'year': '2008', 'month': '02'}]",,"[{'smoking': None, 'gamble': None}]","[{'phone': '123456789', 'email': 'info@gmail.com'}]",MBA,NY,new york
```

new code

```
import pandas as pd
import json
data = []
add_header = True
with open('C:\\Users\\jeri\\Desktop\\1.json',encoding='utf-8') as f_json:
    for line in f_json:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
dfe = explode('name').explode('info').explode("Hobby"),pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.name),
                                                                  pd.json_normalize(df.info),
                                                                  pd.json_normalize(df.Hobby)], axis=1)
dfe.to_csv('C:\\Users\\jeri\\Desktop\\11.csv', index=False,encoding='utf-8',header=add_header)
add_header = False
```

output

```
id,sex,age,other,Education,School,Fn,Ln,start_date,year,month,address.State,address.City,title.name,title.Exp,phone,email,smoking,gamble
aa,male,45,,MBA,"{'State': 'NY', 'City': 'new york'}",jeri,teri,2001-09,2001,05,NY,new york,Doctor,head,123456789,info@gmail.com,,
aa,female,34,,MBA,"{'State': 'NY', 'City': 'new york'}",lo,li,2008-11,2008,02,NY,new york,Doctor,hand,123456789,info@gmail.com,,
```

Comment: import pandas pd
pd.json_normalize(data)

Comment: yes, but it doesn't convert all json files, just parts

Comment: Please, show what the desired output is.

Comment: One way is to flatten a deeply nested json. then run pd.to_csv on that flattened json.

Comment: also does your json file contain a lines of json dicts? looks like it. in that case it's just any file with a json extension. it's not a valid json format. nonetheless, I get your question now.

Comment: list needs `explode` to be able to do `pd.json_normalize` on the dict inside the list.   `df = pd.json_normalize(data);  pd.conat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.explode('name').name), pd.json_normalize(df.explode('info').info), ... (do same thing for all other list of dicts)], axis=1)`

Comment: Can you provide the full code, if it works, I'll accept it as an answer and click to help  @Emma

Comment: i get an error, `raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError`   @Emma

Comment: Could you add current code and stacktrace to your question?

Comment: I updated the code in the theme,，Got an error message: `raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError` @Emma

Comment: Could you separate `df = pd.json_normalize(data)` and `concat` into 2 line (and remove ";") and execute again and let me know on which line you are getting the exception? Also, you need to assign the result of concat back to df.

Comment: I edited it as you said but got the same error，@Emma

Comment: Right, I expected it but I wanted to know which line you are getting the error.  Could you point the line or function where you are getting the `NotImplementedError`?

Comment: ok i updated the question to see it，@Emma

Comment: My bad, change `explode('info').info` to `explode('info')['info']`.   `info` was a reserved keyword.   Although, please note that, this works only if you ALWAYS have 1 dict within each list.   I skipped to use `concat` and `json_normalize` in 1-line but you may want to separate it to be more robust, like do `df = explode('name').explode('info')...` and then `pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.name), ...)`

Comment: get a new error, `NameError: name 'explode' is not defined`，@Emma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) flattens the dictionary to columns. When you have `list`, you need to [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the list that transform the list into rows.
If you have dictionary inside the list, you need to apply the `json_normalize` again on the exploded column.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = []
# read_json normalizes the top layer.
df_it = pd.read_json('C:\\Users\\jeri\\Desktop\\1.json', encoding='utf-8', lines=True, chunksize=100000)
for sub in df_it:
    data.append(sub)

df = pd.concat(data)

# You just need to flatten the list of dict additionally.
# If you are using pandas >= 1.3.0, df = df.explode(['name', 'info', 'Hobby'])
# Otherwise, explode only takes 1 column at a time.
df = df.explode('name').explode('info').explode("Hobby")
df = pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True), 
                pd.json_normalize(df.name), 
                # info is reserved keyword (dataframe function name, you cannot use df.info), 
                # change it to accessing by df['info']
                pd.json_normalize(df['info']), 
                pd.json_normalize(df.Hobby)], axis=1)
# Drop the exploded column, the contents inside the column is extracted to columns already
df = df.drop(['name', 'info', 'Hobby'], axis=1)

df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\jeri\\Desktop\\11.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Another thing to consider is when you have multiple `json_normalize`, you need to make sure that key in each dict column is not shared amongst the other columns you try to `json_normalize`. In your sample, I didn't see any of same key name, so I did `concat` and `json_normalize` in 1 shot.

However, if you have same key name in dict, you need to take step by step. Do `json_normalize` on 1 exploded column and rename column(s), then do another `json_normalize` on another exploded column.

Comment: I see you are asking about this type of question multiple times.  I added the link for the functions that is useful in your operations, so take a look at the link to know the usage and what does the function do.   Also, it would be good to look at the dataframe after each line or each function or try executing separately, and see what each function do to the current dataframe.

Comment: I ran the code but I got an error,，`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`，You can also see the full info in the question，@Emma

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: I see, I run it with no errors, but it doesn't convert all objects because `school` isn't converted. @Emma

Comment: Yes, I am not doing all.  I gave you the idea, I think you can apply it to `school` now.  I hope you are not just pasting the entire code and bringing back the exact error without debugging/working out from it.  It might sound impolite but I hope you understand I am putting my time on this and I am hoping you are getting an educational value out from this.

Comment: yes i am learning it.